# Find Positions of a Character in a String

Tags: java, string, character, indices

How can I find a character in a `String` and print the position of character all over the string? For example, I want to find positions of `'o'` in this string : `"you are awesome honey"` and get the answer = `1 12 17`.

I wrote this, but it doesn't work :

```
public class Pos {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String string = ("You are awesome honey");
        for (int i = 0 ; i<string.length() ; i++)
        if (string.charAt(i) == 'o')
        System.out.println(string.indexOf(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're expecting code, you need to edit your question to add a tag telling us what language/environment you're working in. Also, have you made any attempt yourself? If so, please add that also.

Comment: I'm Edited my question , is that format something like this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost right. The issue is your last line. You should print `i` instead of `string.indexOf(i)`:

```
public class Pos{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String string = ("You are awesome honey");
        for (int i = 0 ; i<string.length() ; i++)
        if (string.charAt(i) == 'o')
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RastinRadvar When an answer works for you, you're supposed to accept it.

Comment: Thanks Dude ,It's Done . I'm New Here And don't know How To Work It Already . I'll Find out Everything soon , thanks again for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Start from the first character and iterate over all the characters till you reach the end. At each step test whether the character is a 'o'. If it is then print the position.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static ArrayList<String> getCharPosition(String str, char mychar) {
            ArrayList<String> positions = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (str.length() == 0)
                return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) == mychar) {
                    positions.add(String.valueOf(i));
                }
            }

            return positions;
    }

String string = ("You are awesome honey");

ArrayList<String> result = getCharPosition(string, 'o');

for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i ++) {
    System.out.println("char position is: " + result.get(i));
}
```

**Output:**

```
char position is: 1
char position is: 12
char position is: 17
```

Comment: Thanks , It's Working Too but i didn't like to Use Arrays . I Found my answer but thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Here in Java:

```
    String s = "you are awesome honey";
    char[] array = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == 'o'){
            System.out.println(i);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to find all positions of specific character in string

```
public ArrayList<Integer> findPositions(String string, char character) {
    ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        if (string.charAt(i) == character) {
           positions.add(i);
        }
    }
    return positions;
}
```

And use it by

```
ArrayList<Integer> result = findPositions("You are awesome honey",'o'); 
// result will contains 1,12,17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    //Please remember that the first array position will always start from 0
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name = ("Renuncia Boric!!!");
        for (int i = 0 ; i<name.length() ; i++)
            if (name.charAt(i) == 'i')
                System.out.println("The letter selected is present at the position: "+i+".");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The letter selected is present at the position: 6.
The letter selected is present at the position: 12.
```